# Does the following structure have a name in grammar?

Tags: grammar, formality

The structure in question is in the form of `Don't + be + verb + ing + rest of the sentence`
I've heard sentences like this in movies, especially by African Americans, and it seems to be something informal. Does anybody have any information about this form of sentence like what the name of this structure is(if in fact it has been given any name) or the meaning and usage.

examples:
Don't be hatin' me